# Check the date format of input argument

Tags: sql-server, date

I am working on excel upload functionality , where some date will be there in EXCEL file.I have to check for the date format. If the format is **YYYY-MM-DD** then only i have to upload the data in table .otherwise raise an error. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
SET DATEFORMAT YMD;
SELECT CASE WHEN @myDate LIKE '[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]' 
THEN --Yourlogic 
ELSE 'ERROR' END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
-- use these sessions settings
SET LANGUAGE us_english;
SET DATEFORMAT ymd;

-- select only data with valid date
SELECT * FROM excel_data WHERE ISDATE(column_to_check) = 1;
```

Comment: Just wrap this up in IF/ELSE. Other than that, much better than using `LIKE`.

Comment: this will also accept yyyy/mm/dd ,but i dont want that

Comment: you can add at the end additional condition: `and (column_to_check) like '____-__-__'`